# How can I get the total number of days fr a specific month and year using JQuery custom UI?

Tags: jquery

Is there any fnction in the JQuery datepicker custom ui where I can get the total number of days by passing on the month name and year?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use regular Javascript. No need for jQuery. I'm not sure what the date picker returns but if you can get the year like '2012' and the month like '2':

```
var year = 2012;
var month = 2;
var days = Math.round(((new Date(year, month))-(new Date(year, month-1)))/86400000);
```

Since 2012 is a leap year, and 2 is February the above code days becomes `29`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var y = 2012;
var m = 2;
var x = new Date(y,m,1,-1).getDate();
alert(x);
```

Output: 29

Comment: How is this better than other up-voted answers? Please add some more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the dates using the following methods, using a start and end date:

```
function parseDate(str) {
    var mdy = str.split('/')
    return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[0]-1, mdy[1]);
}

function daydifference(first, second) {
    return (second-first)/(1000*60*60*24)
}

//example
    alert(daydifference(parseDate($('#firstDate').val()), parseDate($('#endDate').val())));
```

More links you can have a look at :

[Jquery get total days from 2 inputs and display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608767/jquery-get-total-days-from-2-inputs-and-display)

[How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

```
var y = 2012;
var m = 2;
var x = new Date(y,m,1,-1).getDate();
alert(x);
```

Explaining above answer... (couldn't comment there as my reputation is <50)

It simply constructs a new date object refering to date (remember month values are 0-11 so m=2 implies march) 1 March 2012 minus 1 hour which in turn will give 29 Feb 2014 23:00:00 and .getDate() doing rest of the work.

I think its better than other upvoted answers due to simplicity, less space & time complexity.